# OS X: Trying to run an application in terminal and create an image of it

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, screen-capture, ansi

I am trying to run a program such as tload or slurm which graphs a system metric over time, and make its input into an image that has ANSI color support.

The best I can think of is using screencapture on a window ID, but that is quite a hassle and not ideal for what I am trying to do.